# 'Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value', despite every property having a value

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building my first Swift/iOS application.  I'm currently using Firebase for the database.

I've been facing a frustrating issue, where upon hitting the register button after filling out the sign-up form, I receive the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

When I look at the object, every property seems to have its value.  Here is my Firebase sign up function:

```
 func handleRegister() {
        if let email = emailTextField.text, let password = passwordTextField.text, let fullName = fullNameTextField.text, let age = Int(ageTextField.text!), let username = userNameTextField.text {

            Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password ) { (user, error) in
                // ...

                if let firebaseError = error {
                    print(firebaseError.localizedDescription)
                    return
                }

                let userID = user!.uid

                //Instantiate our User model - set key values equal to optionals above from sign up form
                let userAccount = User(userId: userID, email: email, fullName: fullName, age: age, username: username)

                //Initialize an empty dictionary to hold the keys and values to upload to Firebase
                var userAccountDict = [String:AnyObject]()

                //Use a dictionary method to update the keys and matching values. The values are the ones from UserAccount model's properties and the keys are what we decide we want them to be named in FirebaseDatabase. Use these keys to extract the values
                userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.userId as AnyObject, forKey: "userId")
                userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.email as AnyObject, forKey: "email")
                userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.fullName as AnyObject, forKey: "fullName")
                userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.age as AnyObject, forKey: "age")
                userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.username as AnyObject, forKey: "username")


                //Upload dictionary with the keys and values set above. The database will hold these key/value pairs under the "users" node.
                self.ref.child("users").child(user!.uid).setValue(userAccountDict)
                print("User registered in Firebase with a userId of " + user!.uid)


            }
        }
    }
```

The Sign up process is currently done programmatically, as opposed to a storyboard.  Here is the button, where I ultimately call my handleRegister() function:

```
//    REGISTER BUTTON
    let registerButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.system)
        button.isHidden = true
        button.isEnabled = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.setTitle("Register", for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.setTitleColor(.white, for: UIControlState.normal)
        button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 16)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(toAppFeed), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)


        return button
    }()
```

Here is what I see on the left pane next to my console:
[image]

The only thing I see that is nil is the error, which I imagine should be nil, since Firebase isn't throwing any.  Even so, it's not in the object that I am posting to Firebase.  I should mention that when I check Firebase, I see every user I've created, however none of the user data that I'm gathering from the handleRegister() function is saved into the database.

I've been working with Firebase for a few months now, and have not faced this issue before.  I've looked at other SO questions, but none seem to solve this specific issue.  The only thing I can think of at this point is that something is still nil when the handleRegister() is called, and gains a value afterwards.  But I'm not sure.

Any help on this very much appreciated.

EDIT - Here's where the error shows after 'sign up' is pressed after filling out the form:
[image]

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Instead of `userAccountDict.updateValue(userAccount.userId as AnyObject, forKey: "userId")`, you should use the Swift dictionary syntax: `userAccountDict["userId"] = userAccount.userId`, though I don't think that's what is causing the crash

Comment: handleRegister it is an asynchronous method you should use a completion handler

Comment: Hey @Connor, thanks for your message.  It happens on my self.ref.child line.  I'll add an image of the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was indeed being force unwrapped, however it was none of my variables.

Firebase reference is initially set as

```
ref: DatabaseReference!
```

In self.ref.child, ref needs a ?:

```
self.ref?.child
```

Of course, the console didn't reveal that all too well.  So the ref was being force unwrapped, and I wasn't checking to make sure it existed when I used it in my handleRegister() function.

I also forgot to instantiate my Firebase reference in viewDidLoad().

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to assign the values in the dictionary with the key reference, however those keys are not available yet, and that's the issue believe me.

here's the solution 
var userAccountDict = [String:Any] ()

userAccountDict["userId"] = userAccount.userId 
and so on...

good luck :)

Comment: So that's what making it a crash, I did mention that the key is not available and he's trying to update the value for that key.

Comment: That would be strange though, since I've used this method before in other test projects when creating a new user, and it's worked.  I'll give it a shot though.  Thanks